# How do you map Command/Apple option in vim

Tags: vim

I am going through this document and this is what I gathered.

```
        <Esc>                Escape key
        <C-G>                CTRL-G
        <Up>                 cursor up key
        <C-LeftMouse>        Control- left mouse click
        <S-F11>              Shifted function key 11
        <M-a>                Meta- a  ('a' with bit 8 set)
        <M-A>                Meta- A  ('A' with bit 8 set)
        <t_kd>               "kd" termcap entry (cursor down key)
```

However I don't see how I can map Command/Apple key here. I am using plugin [mentioned here](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2009/1/28/the-future-of-fuzzyfinder-textmate). It works great. I open a tab and then I hit Command-R and I get the list of files. I could not find where the mapping is done between Command-R and the function.  I am using vim settings as mentioned [here](http://github.com/neerajdotname/vim/tree/master)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[the modifier "D" stands for the "Command" key](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_use/browse_thread/thread/bff6b7138d0a5f1b/cff688171c4714af?lnk=raot)

Comment: I know this is super old now.. but is there a name for this type of format: `<C-G>`? I've personally only encountered it in Vim but am not even sure how to search for more info. As you can imagine, searching `<C-G>` doesn't return the greatest results ;)

Comment: @Benjamin The Vim documentation might be helpful, especially [the section key-notation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#keycodes). You could then also use the the key code value with google, like "vim Ctrl-G".

Comment: Thanks for the resource @ax.!

Comment: Is there a way to make this word on terminal vim (not macvim nor gui vim) ?

Answer (score 2):

Or T- in gvim, but it doesn't work with all keys, e. g. not with letters. T-CR, T-F5 or T-DELETE are OK though. Availability could be checked with ^K or ^V